# Sorting MySQL results based on client side input

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I've looked around and played with it myself, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Not even almost. What I am trying to do, is I have a database that has a list of items, which expire on a future date. I would like to have a date selection box, where you can choose a date off of a calender (which I can achieve), but then only show records whose expiration date is prior to that date. So if my dates range from today till Sept. of next year, and I choose December 15th, 2012, I will only see records whose expiration date is between today and December 15th, 2012. Any help would be appreciated.

I would post some code, but nothing I have even comes close to achieving this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Post your current code :). It is rather unclear where exactly you are having problems.

Comment: Do you need help with the query, the PHP code, or both?

Comment: the query mainly. I now have the date selection setup, have it sending the selection through the url using GET, and that works fine, I just cant get it to display only records prior to that date. It either displays none, or all.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, Its just difficult to post code when there really is none. I understand all the setup prior to the actual mysql sorting, and I understand that to an extent, just not sure on this exact setup how I can get the query to show only dates prior to the input date. I'm using the date datatype, and my input is formatted the same way, just not sure of exact query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL should be something like this, if this isn't working set up a sqlfiddle and give us an example of your data at the least.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ExpirationDate BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. didn't even think of BETWEEN condition. Thanks so much!!